# xcode not giving an output while using pthread library

Tags: c++, xcode, posix

smaller programs work just fine, but as soon as I start writing over 30 lines, it seems like xcode wants to execute, but nothing really happens. This is the code I have written, I can't find any errors, but maybe there is an explanation for my issues.
    `

```
    using namespace std;
    int errorCounter = 0;
```

class Vector
{
public:
Vector(unsigned int size = 10000) : size_(size)
{
    vector_ = new int[size_];
    set(0);
}

 ~Vector()
{
    delete[] vector_;
}

bool setAndTest(int n)
{
    set(n);
    return test(n);
}


private:
void set(int n)
{
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<size_; i++) vector_[i] = n;
}

bool test(int n)
{
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<size_; i++) if(vector_[i] != n) return false;
    return true;
}

int*           vector_;
unsigned int   size_;
};

Vector vec;
int threads = 50;

void *writer(void *ptr)
{
int *threadIDconvert = (int*)(ptr);
while(1)
{
    if (!vec.setAndTest(*threadIDconvert)) {
        errorCounter++;
        cout<<"error arrised from thread ID " << *threadIDconvert << " error     number" << errorCounter<<endl;
        usleep(100000);
    }
}
return NULL;
}


int main() {
//int threads;
//cout << "enter an amount of threads: min 1 max 100" <<endl;
//cin>>threads;
if(threads<1){cout<<"you screwed up"<<endl; return 0;}
else if (threads>100) {cout<<"you screwed up"<<endl; return 0;}
pthread_t threadID[threads];


for (int x=0; x<=threads; x++) {
    pthread_create(&threadID[x], NULL, writer, &vec);
}
for (int CID=0; CID<=threads; CID++) {
    pthread_join(threadID[CID], NULL);
}
return 0;
}
`

Hope someone can help out, and sorry that I didn't show all of my includes, I don't know how to on stack overflow (and I know I can use mutex and what not, this is just a try out program :-) )

Comment: I see out-of-bounds accesses in `threadID`, no synchronization in `Vector`, and an invalid conversion from `Vector*` through `void*` to `int*`. The undefined behaviour is strong in this one.

Comment: should I set the input parameter from a `void*` to a `vector*` instead? As for synchronization in the vector class, its supposed to be like that (for now). And for the out of bounds access in `threadID`, I dont understand, where have I gone wrong there?

Comment: 1. You need to cast back to the original type, but it looks like you want to pass an id rather than the vector; 2. No, it's not supposed to be like that because concurrent modification of it makes your code invalid; 3. An array with k elements is indexed from 0 to k-1.

Comment: Thanks, the only thing I needed to change was to pass the ID, had not thought that thought.